# Multi-core multi-process node application and single-core single-process node application performance What is the difference

Tags: node.js, libuv

I'm confused libuv have thread-pool mechanism, What is the necessity of using multiple processes?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/threadpool.html) says that (emphasis mine):

> libuv provides a threadpool which **can be used to run user code and get notified in the loop thread**. This thread pool is **internally used to run all file system operations**, as well as **getaddrinfo and getnameinfo** requests.

To sum up, first of all `libuv` uses multiple threads internally to run blocking operations without blocking the loop(s) (filesystem, DNS).
Secondly, you can use them more or less for the same reasons. Imagine you have a cpu bound task that you don't know how/don't want to/cannot split in parts to be executed through different ticks, you can still spawn a thread (a work request actually) and let it execute on a separate thread. This way, your loop won't be in a stall waiting for those tasks.

Comment: sry . I'm not really understand you means. Even if there is no multi-process libuv threads will still make context switch in a number of kernel. I thought , Whether it is multi-task not influence the event-loop performance

Comment: @bugall In a multi processor system, usually more loops are spawn with a balancer to distribute the load. So you can think of them as isolated processes on a single cpu.